# Confusion about the notation for the tangent vector to the FRLW's metric congruence

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, cosmology, metric-tensor, notation

I want to solve the following problem (Problem 2.2 on Poisson's book "A Relativist's Toolkit"):

The FLRW metric is

$$\text{d} s^2 = -\text{d} t^2 + a(t)^2 \Bigg(\frac{\text{d} r^2}{1 - kr^2} + r^2 \text{d} \Omega^2 \Bigg)$$

The vector tangent to the congruence is $u^a = \partial_t x^a$. Show that the congruence is geodesic.

As I understand it, I have to show that $u^a \nabla_a u^b = 0$, however in order to prove this, I must know who $x^a$ is, which is the thing that confuses me. It may seem like a rather obvious question, but who is $x^a$? I'm honestly lost and I don't know how to tackle this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Coordinates**

The $x^{a}$ you're asking about is a coordinate system, a way of labeling points on a spacetime manifold. As such, it does not really belong to anybody.

You need to modify the way of thinking that was possible in Special Relativity - where inertial frames with an observer at their origin could provide us with coordinates as well. We can use frames in GR and make measurement with them, but these give rise to coordinates only local to an observer - see the Riemann normal coordinates https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates.

Typically in GR, coordinates are inherently stripped away from any observer.
They serve to label the points on the spacetime manifold (events) in some consistent, but otherwise arbitrary way.

Think of a sphere $S_{2}$ and of the angular coordinates that label points on the sphere $(\theta, \phi$). These do not cover the whole sphere, but we do not care about this here. We have a lot of freedom even in assigning these two coordinates - we can rotate the assignments of points in an arbitrary way. Needless to say, many other coordinate systems on a sphere are possible.

If it helps you to think of a person making global measurements, you can imagine an absolute narrator. They have the freedom to assign any label to any spacetime event. Of course, *well-behavedness* of this assignment is assumed.

Such a narrator might even be able to separate the spacetime into time and space, creating a so-called *foliation* of the spacetime manifold.
$$\mathcal{M} = \bigcup_{t\in\mathbb{R}}\Sigma_{t} = \mathbb{R}\times \Sigma $$

Such a spacetime splitting is possible whenever a smooth spacetime manifold has a global Cauchy surface $\Sigma$, which your has.

This *absolute narrator* idea of time lies in $\mathbb{R}$, and his idea of simultaneity slices - spacelike hypersurfaces - is in $\Sigma$.

**Curves and congruence**

Now, there is a notion of a congruence of curves, which is a family of observers, whose four-velocities form the tangent vector field to their worldlines.

A worldline (the curve along which the observer moves) is an assignment:
$$ \gamma : I \rightarrow \mathcal{M} $$

We might have a family of such curves, which is then called the congruence.

$$ \gamma : I\times J \rightarrow \mathcal{M},$$

where the $I$ is some parameter along the congruence and the $J$ distinguishes between the curves (it could be a Cartesian product of three intervals if you want to distinguish in three dimensions).

Now, the vector field tangent to the conguruence is defined as

$$ X(\gamma(t,s)) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \gamma(t, s) $$

Coming back to the example of the sphere, the observers moving in the azimuthal direction are collectively described by the $\partial_{\theta} $ vector field, and in the polar direction by  $\partial_{\phi}$.

In your case, you have the congruence of curves (possible observers) defined by the vector field
$$ X = \frac{\partial }{\partial t}.$$

The integral curves of this vector field, in $(t, r, \theta, \phi) $ coordinates, are simply given by:

$$ x^{\mu} \circ \gamma (\tau) = ( t(\tau), r_{0} , \theta_{0}, \phi_{0})$$

So in these coordinates, observers in the congruence defined as being tangent in the time direction, are maintaining constant spatial coordinates and moving forward only in time.

Therefore $u=\partial_{t} $.

Can you now find whether this vector field satisfies the geodesic congruence condition?

**If you tried it yourself but something does not work out**

$$\nabla_{\partial t}\partial t = \partial_{t}( \partial_{t})^{\mu} \partial_{\mu} + \Gamma^{\mu}_{t \nu}( \partial_{t})^{\nu}  \partial_{\mu}$$

We have trivially $(\partial_{t})^{\mu} = \delta^{\mu t} $, so the first term in the above is zero and in the second one, the lower index of the Christoffel symbol changes from $\nu$ to $t$.
[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer. I suppose, then, that $x^a$ is standard notation when we refer to coordinates? Because the book doesn't mention it in the problem. If I may inquire further, in these coordinates $x^a \rightarrow (t, r, \theta, \varphi)$, are the scale factors implicitly included in the coordinates, or are they present only in the basis vectors? Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, the $x^{a}$ or $x^{\mu} $ is often used to denote collectively the four coordinates. These are, by the way, nothing more than scalar functions on the manifold. These take a point and take it to its zeroth, first, second or third label. The spatial coordinates $(r, \theta, \phi) $ in which you have the metric above are not co-moving, i.e. they are not multiplied by the scale factor. Therefore, the coordinate basis vectors $(\partial_{r}, \partial_{\theta}, \partial_{\phi}) $ that correspond to them are not rescaled in any way. You can see that by computing their magnitude, it changes.

Comment: If you used rescaled coordinates, you'd find that the lengths of the corresponding coordinate vectors are not changing, as they are multiplied by the inverse of the scale factor with respect to the unrescaled vectors and cancel the scale factor contribution from the metric.

Comment: Sorry, I think I phrased my question wrong. By scale factors I meant the following: suppose we're in euclidean space in spherical coordinates. Then, the basis vectors are: $\textbf{e}_r = \hat{\textbf{r}}$, $\textbf{e}_\theta = r \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}$, and $\textbf{e}_\varphi = r \sin (\theta) \hat{\boldsymbol{\varphi}}$. Both $\textbf{e}_\theta$ and $\textbf{e}_\varphi$ have scale factors different than 1, these are $r$ and $r \sin (\theta)$ respectively. With the notation $x^a \rightarrow (r, \theta, \varphi)$, are the scale factors implicitly included in the coordinates?

Comment: In Euclidean space you calculate the length of vectors using the Euclidean metric. For example the $\partial_{\theta} $ coordinate basis vector is not a unit vector field, but the $\mathbf{e}_{\theta}$ is. Similarly, the length of the coordinate basis vectors in your spacetime is given by your metric. You see that in order to get unit length, rescaling by an additional factor of $a(t) $ is necessary for the angular coordinate vector fields. The radial coordinate vector field has to be rescaled by that factor you have in the metric if you want it to have unit length everywhere.

Comment: Understood. Thank you for your answer and comments. You were very helpful.

Comment: Glad to be of help!